# No output from std::process::Command

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I wanted to run clippy using process::Command but it doesn't seem to be working.

I ran cargo build on this:

```
use std::env;
use std::process::Command;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let pwd = env::current_dir();
    match pwd {
        Ok(data) => {
            println!("{}", &data.display());
            let output = Command::new("cargo")
            .arg("clippy")
            .output()
            .expect("there was an error");

            io::stdout().write_all(&output.stdout).unwrap();
        },
        Err(_) => (),
    }
}
```

than executed the binary in the root of another rust project. But I don't seem to be getting any output. I've tried replacing `cargo clippy` with `ls` and that ran normally. Properly listing all files in that directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Like most compilers, `cargo clippy` only outputs errors and warnings on stderr, not stdout.

Comment: If your project involves parsing the output of clippy, note that you can configure it [to output diagnostics in machine-readable JSON instead](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/json.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mcarton pointed out `cargo clippy` does not print anything to stdout.
Only to stderr. So adding the output of stderr prints more text:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::process::Command;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let pwd = env::current_dir();
    match pwd {
        Ok(data) => {
            println!("{}", &data.display());
            let output = Command::new("cargo")
                .arg("clippy")
                .output()
                .expect("there was an error");

            io::stdout().write_all(&output.stdout).unwrap();
            // add this line to print stderr output too
            io::stderr().write_all(&output.stderr).unwrap();
        },
        Err(_) => (),
    }
}
```

In the example above we wrote the output of stderr of `output` to our application stderr.

output.stderr -> app.stderr:

```rust
io::stderr().write_all(&output.stderr).unwrap();
```

If we want to write it to stdout instead we can use.

output.stderr -> app.stdout:

```rust
io::stdout().write_all(&output.stderr).unwrap();
```

Comment: That makes sense. I was so focused on stdout that I forgot about stderr. Thank you.