# "git submodule update" in build.rs with std::process::Command has no effect

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo

I'm trying to port C++ software to Rust and one of the parts is fetching a git submodule with a C++ library. I'd like to integrate that action into my custom build.rs script instead of [forcing a user to do that manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69965299) before running `cargo build`. Here is my `build.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    std::process::Command::new("git")
        .args([
            "submodule",
            "update",
            "--init",
            "--depth 1",
            "--recommend-shallow",
    ])
    .output()
    .expect("Failed to fetch git submodules!");

    // here C++ code compilation with cc::Build happens
}
```

Unfortunately: the command didn't execute -> the submodule wasn't fetched -> C++ compiler started complaining about missing headers -> cargo threw an error. Otherwise than that `build.rs` is totally fine, because it worked perfectly after running `git submodule update` manually before `cargo build`. Suprisingly enough changing the command to `echo cargo:warning=test`, catching the output of the `std::process::Command` and [outputting it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66321706) with `io::stdout().write_all(&output.stdout).unwrap();` resulted in cargo correctly reporting a warning. `touch`ing a test file and later `rm`ing it after the compilation worked as well. Why `git` doesn't work, but these commands do?

Comment: What's the output of only that snippet?

Comment: @tifrel I won't paste stdout here since it's just compiler's "dude, where's my header?" rambling. Stderr is a bit more interesting, though, because it's `git submodule`'s usage info, which is printed every time you enter a bad command. It made me think and I've just split the `--depth 1` argument into 2 separate ones. Sure enough stderr is now empty, but the build script still errors out with litany of errors in stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally dropped the submodule while trying to solve this issue, which I detected by running `git submodule update` manually and achieving no effect. `cargo build` works **perfectly** automagically after the fix described in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71726734#comment126763978_71726734). Please pretend this didn't happen and you haven't seen this question.

Answer (score 1):

Given [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71730006/7525350), I'd also like to suggest taking a look at the [return type of `std::process::Command::output`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/process.rs.html#896-901). This is an `std::io::Result`, and while I cannot tell for sure, I would expect this to fail e.g. if the specified command is not accessible, **but return an `Ok` variant on non-zero exit codes**.

You can (and probably should) inspect the exit code from the obtained `Output` struct whenever you run `std::process::Command`, such that you can pinpoint the step at which your build script fails.